# Refrashing the Javascript File without page refresh.

Tags: javascript

I am working on a very complex web site which is wizard based and have many JavaScript files included.

Now problem is if I pass through many step and at some later stage I find a JavaScript problem, as I fix it I have to load the page again and as I load the page again the Wizard will be started from step one again.

What I want is if I make JavaScript change in a file, there should be a possibility to refresh the JavaScript file through Firebug or something like it.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Maybe the problem is rather that 'when you reload the page, the wizard starts again'. Why is this? And are you sure your users will like this? An F5, history.back or connection loss happens often enough, people hate having to redo stuff..

Comment: @Konerak: That's a good point - would it be posible to store the necessary data into the URL's `#fragment=1;like=this` , so that the form is more resilient to reload?

Comment: Either in the URL, or in cookies. You can store the entire dataset, or just an ID and keep the data in your database (if persistent), memcached (if you have that) or SESSION (if you are working with sessions on serverside).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not really. You could try to change the `<script>`'s `src` attribute to something like `/your/script.js?timestamp=1234567890`, but this doesn't give a reliable guarantee that the script will be loaded again.

You could add another `script` element into the DOM, but then you'd have *two* very similar scripts loaded at the same time, which may be problematic.